# windows commands are not excecute in my php script

Tags: java, php

I have a java file and it will generate a report. I want to execute this within in a php script. Im using the exec() function in php:

```
<?php
$output = array();
$return  = 0;
exec("D:");
exec("cd class");
exec("java login username password id name Daily Detailed  20120820",$output,$return);
?>
```

When I execute this commands in windows command prompt it works properly. But not in a php script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`exec('"pushd d:\class & java login username password id name Daily Detailed  20120820"',$output,$return);)`

The `&` is because you have multiple commands, and the context is not going to be remembered between exec's.

Also, [php exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) calls `cmd /c` on your exec command, so you need an extra pair of quotes around the whole call.

(`cmd /?` from your command prompt explains more on `/c`).

Comment: this not worked for me.if i need to change anything in php.ini file for exce command

Comment: I've made a bug fix with the single quote being in the wrong place - did you fix that too before trying? I've updated the solution. Also, what do you mean by "not worked"? :-)

Comment: Anyway, you can test if your php setup is OK by `exec("dir",$output$,$return)`

Comment: the java class file will produce a report when it excecuted. when i do this in cmd prompt work perfectly. but this not worked in php script

Comment: You have to tell me what "not worked" means. Any error messages? Does `exec("dir",$output,$return);` work and display a directory listing in the output? Have you read the `php_exec` documentation link in the solution?